# R_alloc and alignment considerations

Tags: c, r, memory-alignment

I'm writing an R extension that requires me to allocate memory for an array of structs.  The structs contain integers, SEXPs, character pointers, e.g. something like:

```
struct my_struct {
  int a;
  SEXP b;
  const char * d;
  const char * e[3];
};
```

I'm hoping to allocate memory for the array using something like:

```
struct my_struct * arr = (struct my_struct *) R_alloc(10, sizeof(my_struct));
```

This works in the strictest sense of the word, but I'm given pause by the following comment from [**WRE**](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Transient-storage-allocation):

> The memory returned is only guaranteed to be aligned as required for double pointers: **take precautions if casting to a pointer which needs more**.

I am not concerned about speed or space as I don't expect my arrays to be large or accessed frequently.  I do however want to avoid crashes.  My understanding is that misaligned memory access is really only a performance issue for x86 architectures.  Furthermore, since it seems nowadays R is primarily for x86 architectures (based on CRAN tests), and I'm not concerned about performance, I shouldn't have any problems doing this.

Am I setting myself up for trouble?

---

EDIT: I'm assuming here that "double pointers" means pointers to doubles, and not pointers to pointers as seems to be the informal convention in some places.  FWIW the code in `R_alloc` (src/main/memory.c@~2700) wants to allocate in multiples of `sizeof(VECREC)`, where `VECREC` is `union(SEXP, double)` (src/include/Defn.h@~410), plus header offset.  Presumably this is where the alignment guarantee for doubles comes from, but I'm not sure why this would be a problem for larger structs.  Granted, I'm not particularly experienced at this.

Comment: I get the feeling that the `SEXP` must be the **first** member in the struct (*smart union* method) Unless R_alloc() does that for you automatically. And:you dont want the cast. If the SEXP is a reference to another object,you need to take care of the reference counting.

Comment: `My understanding is that misaligned memory access is really only a performance issue for x86 architectures` **NO!!!** unaligned acces leads to violations and bus-errors/segfaults. BTW: your code looks correct. (and the R documentation is terrible)

Comment: @wildplasser Thanks for the input.

Comment: And the *double pointers* part in the text could be there to allow 80 bit ints to be aligned (these exist on some platforms) The crux is : the R_alloc() returns a pointer *suitably aligned* for *any* object(probably 8 chars, or a multiple of it, suchas theheader/SEXP). (and your struct has the alignment requirements of its first member, an int (probably 4chars)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not an expert on the matter, but according to at least [this site](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/#_structure_alignment_and_padding):

> In general, a struct instance will have the alignment of its widest scalar member. Compilers do this as the easiest way to ensure that all the members are self-aligned for fast access.

So in this case, the struct should have an alignment compatible with what `R_alloc` allocates, since it's largest member will be the `SEXP` (probably, I guess it might be possible for `char *` to be bigger on some systems, but seems unlikely), and `R_alloc` allocates in multiples of `union(SEXP, double)`, as documented in the question.

One other thing perhaps worth pointing out is that the recommended ordering of the elements in a struct is from largest alignment requirement to lowest, and right now we start with an `int`, which is the smallest.